# In Asp.net which controls are n't compatible inside updatepanel like fck editor

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, fckeditor

In Asp.net which controls are n't compatible inside updatepanel like fck editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the FileUpload component does not work inside UpdatePanel (without additional coding, at least)